# Trouble handling single and double quotes in inline JS within a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP function with a variable that includes some inline JS. I've tried escaping all the single and double quotes but it breaks the rest of the page. What's the proper way to write this? Here's an example:

```
function function_name() {
        $variable = '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var AdButler = AdButler || {}; AdButler.ads = AdButler.ads || [];
                var abkw = window.abkw || '';
                var plc347434 = window.plc347434 || 0;
                document.write('<'+'div id="placement_347434_'+plc347434+'"></'+'div>');
                AdButler.ads.push({handler: function(opt){ AdButler.register(172522, 347434, [728,90], 'placement_347434_'+opt.place, opt); }, opt: { place: plc347434++, keywords: abkw, domain: 'servedbyadbutler.com', click:'CLICK_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER' }});
            </script>';
}
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function function_name() {
        $variable = "
            <script>
                var AdButler = AdButler || {}; AdButler.ads = AdButler.ads || [];
                var abkw = window.abkw || '';
                var plc347434 = window.plc347434 || 0;
                document.write('<'+'div id=\"placement_347434_'+plc347434+'\"></'+'div>');
                AdButler.ads.push({handler: function(opt){ AdButler.register(172522, 347434, [728,90], 'placement_347434_'+opt.place, opt); }, opt: { place: plc347434++, keywords: abkw, domain: 'servedbyadbutler.com', click:'CLICK_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER' }});
            </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   function function_name() {
        $variable = <<<JSSCRIPT
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var AdButler = AdButler || {}; AdButler.ads = AdButler.ads || [];
                var abkw = window.abkw || '';
                var plc347434 = window.plc347434 || 0;
                document.write('<'+'div id="placement_347434_'+plc347434+'"></'+'div>');
                AdButler.ads.push({handler: function(opt){ AdButler.register(172522, 347434, [728,90], 'placement_347434_'+opt.place, opt); }, opt: { place: plc347434++, keywords: abkw, domain: 'servedbyadbutler.com', click:'CLICK_MACRO_PLACEHOLDER' }});
            </script>
JSSCRIPT;
return $variable;
}
```

beware no to add spaces before `JSSCRIPT;` - the line before return statement.

Comment: Fun Fact: PHP 7.3 is more permissive with the ending tag. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.heredoc

Comment: @Sammitch good to now , it once was a nightmare for one tiny space that i did not saw .